# Word embeddings in Tensorflow2

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to understand how to use Tensorflow2 to train word embeddings without the preset labels.

In the Tensorflow2 tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/word_embeddings) it shows how to train word embeddings using pre-structured dataset with labels.

```
imdb = keras.datasets.imdb
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(
    num_words=vocab_size)

embedding_dim=16

model = keras.Sequential([
layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen),
layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_data,
    train_labels,
    epochs=30,
    batch_size=512,
    validation_data=(test_data, test_labels))
```

However, I wonder how to train - with Tensorflow2 - the embeddings on the non-labeled text, similar to what can be done with Gensim's Word2Vec?

Comment: The question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555084/tensorflow-2-0-beta-model-fit-throws-valueerror-arguments-and-signature-argu)

Comment: please add the answer from the link you have cited directly here.

Answer (score 0):

Training a Word2Vec model doesn't need labels. It looks up context windows in tokenized sentences, then creates vectors for each unique tokens (words) in sentences.

At the end, distances between different vectors help to create relations of words in embedding layer of neural network. If you give `Trainable=True`parameter to embedding layer, vectors will be updated according to given labels in training phase and model will give better results.